# Filter effectively, given that one criteria is limited to a few values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For a table with a field that is restricted to **a few** values like the `Type` field below.

Ex: Table : Animal

```
Name = "Wuf wuf"
Type = "Dog"
/*More properties*/

Name = "Doge"
Type = "Dog"
/*More properties*/    

Name = "Meow"
Type = "Cat"
/*More properties*/
```

Instead of breaking into multiple different tables (Cats,Dogs), what would be the most efficient strategy to filter by this criteria *first*.

To clarify: I would be doing

```
SELECT * FROM 'Animal' WHERE Type = 'Dog' AND Name = "Wuf Wuf";
```

From my understanding this is not as effective compare to

```
SELECT * FROM 'Dogs' WHERE Name = "Wuf Wuf";
```

even when "Type" is indexed.

In all the cases when I want to select something from this table, I will know and filter by "Type" first

How is this handled normally in MySQL? Is indexing on the **Type** field enough? As the "Type" field is limitted to very few values, is there a better way to structure this?

Comment: If you had multiple tables (1 for each animal) how would you know to select from dogs?Would you ask the end user which table he/she wanted to search? if you also got wuf wuf in wolves would that be ok? Normally you would have a table for animals indexed by type.

Comment: Stick to the Animal table design, so much easier to work with. With proper index, the performance difference would be minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of breaking into multiple different tables (Cats,Dogs), what would be the most efficient strategy to filter by this criteria first.

I don't know what it means to filter by "this category first".  Breaking such a table into separate tables is almost certainly not the right approach if your concern is performance.

If `name` is declared to be unique, then these conditions are probably going to have exactly the same performance:

```
WHERE Type = 'Dog' AND Name = 'Wuf Wuf'
WHERE Name = 'Wuf Wuf'
```

Why?  Because the MySQL optimizer is smart enough to use the index on `name` in both cases.  The additional condition has no impact.

In general, an index on `type` alone would be helpful.  That is, a regular index on a single column that has only a handful of values is generally not useful.  There are two exceptions to "indexes on low-cardinality values being not helpful":

- A clustered index can be handy.
- If one of the values is rare and is also commonly used in queries, then such an index can be helpful.

If you have a query on `Name` and a handful of values for `Type` *and* name is not unique, then the following condition will probably still use an index on `Name`:

```
WHERE Type = 'Dog' AND Name = 'Wuf Wuf'
```

In general, though, you should write the `WHERE` clause on the conditions that are needed for the query.  Use indexes to get the performance that you want.